# Recursively group arrays on multiple keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, count, grouping, field

I've a problem trying to grouping an array with multiples values in php...

Given an array like:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [displayOrder] => 1
                [bannerType] => STC
                [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/7d00621b-471f-4613-bfa4-ab87d0b1f70a
            )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [displayOrder] => 2
            [bannerType] => SLD
            [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/da3e95f9-2bbb-4547-aa04-9b3d01fed1c9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [displayOrder] => 2
            [bannerType] => SLD
            [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/2a01044e-e958-44e0-ae0c-cc8136665941
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [displayOrder] => 2
            [bannerType] => SLD
            [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [displayOrder] => 3
            [bannerType] => GRD
            [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [displayOrder] => 3
            [bannerType] => GRD
            [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [displayOrder] => 4
            [bannerType] => SLD
            [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
        )

      )
```

and i want get like this.. I want group the above array using the displayOrder but index it with bannerType dynamically

```
    Array
    (
    [STC] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 1
                    [bannerType] => STC
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/7d00621b-471f-4613-bfa4-ab87d0b1f70a
                )

        )

    [SLD] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 2
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/da3e95f9-2bbb-4547-aa04-9b3d01fed1c9
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 2
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/2a01044e-e958-44e0-ae0c-cc8136665941
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 2
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

        )

    [GRD] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 3
                    [bannerType] => GRD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 3
                    [bannerType] => GRD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

        )

    [SLD] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 4
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

        )

        )
```

I have tried some code for the the given array to the first

```
           foreach($array as $key => $val){
                $output[$val['displayOrder']][] = $val;
            }
```

and the result is

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 1
                    [bannerType] => STC
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/7d00621b-471f-4613-bfa4-ab87d0b1f70a
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 2
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/da3e95f9-2bbb-4547-aa04-9b3d01fed1c9
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 2
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/2a01044e-e958-44e0-ae0c-cc8136665941
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 2
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 3
                    [bannerType] => GRD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 3
                    [bannerType] => GRD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 4
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code that generates the array in the first place? That would be the logical place to make your changes.

Comment: no..I have to change that after the first array

Comment: I don’t see any place here, where this would need actual recursion.

Comment: _“I have tried some code”_ - and? What was the result?

Comment: Please provide at least your input array in the form of a `var_export` - then we just need to copy the code, to work with what you got, and don’t need to modify what you have currently shown into a workable array representation first.

Comment: i have update my question for which code have i tried

Comment: Your desired output format does not even make sense so far - you can not use `SLD` as key on the top level _twice_, the second item with that key would simply override the first one. (Suggestion - come back here, once you learned at least _some_ basics, maybe?)

Comment: can you tell me if any way i can made this like my output from the first array

Comment: Your output is **invalid**, because array indices must be unique. You cannot use `SLD` as an index twice, as @CBroe mentions. It's impossible to get the output you want, unless you're fine with adding a suffix to the array (i.e. `SLD2` / `SLD4` instead of `SLD`

Comment: thanks a lot :D..@Druth & @CBroe

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is the solution of your problem.

```
$db = Array
    (
        0 => Array
            (
                'displayOrder' => '1',
                'bannerType' => 'STC',
                'targetResult' => 'blob:https://localhost/7d00621b-471f-4613-bfa4-ab87d0b1f70a',
            ),
    1 => Array
        (
            'displayOrder' => '2',
            'bannerType' => 'SLD',
            'targetResult' => 'blob:https://localhost/da3e95f9-2bbb-4547-aa04-9b3d01fed1c9',
        ),
    2 => Array
        (
            'displayOrder' => '2',
            'bannerType' => 'SLD',
            'targetResult' => 'blob:https://localhost/2a01044e-e958-44e0-ae0c-cc8136665941',
        ),
    3 => Array
        (
            'displayOrder' => '2',
            'bannerType' => 'SLD',
            'targetResult' => 'blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770',
        ),
    4 => Array
        (
            'displayOrder' => '3',
            'bannerType' => 'GRD',
            'targetResult' => 'blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770',
        ),
    5 => Array
        (
            'displayOrder' => '3',
            'bannerType' => 'GRD',
            'targetResult' => 'blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770',
        ),
    6 => Array
        (
            'displayOrder' => '4',
            'bannerType' => 'SLD',
            'targetResult' => 'blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770',
        ),
  );
```

Solution:

```
//Distinct Banner Type
$bannerType=array_unique(array_column($db, 'bannerType'));
$newArray=array();
foreach ($bannerType as $value) {
    //Creating new array with distinct banner type
    $newArray[$value]=array();
}
foreach ($db as $value) {
    $newArray[$value['bannerType']][]=$value;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [STC] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 1
                    [bannerType] => STC
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/7d00621b-471f-4613-bfa4-ab87d0b1f70a
                )

        )

    [SLD] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 2
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/da3e95f9-2bbb-4547-aa04-9b3d01fed1c9
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 2
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/2a01044e-e958-44e0-ae0c-cc8136665941
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 2
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 4
                    [bannerType] => SLD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

        )

    [GRD] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 3
                    [bannerType] => GRD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [displayOrder] => 3
                    [bannerType] => GRD
                    [targetResult] => blob:https://localhost/71817ae7-e887-4b0f-982b-a6877fac9770
                )

        )

)
```